# Extending modules and testing class (or instance?) methods in Ruby

Tags: ruby, testing, module

New to Ruby and thank you in advance!
I have 2 files in the same directory. Where.rb =

```
module Where
  def self.where(hash = {})
    self.select do |fixture| #iterate over fixtures indexes |fixture| 
      hash.all?  do |key, value| #return true as long as hash exists
        value === fixture[key]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and test.rb =

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
require './where.rb'

class WhereTest < Minitest::Test
  extend Where
  def setup
    @boris   = {:name => 'Boris The Blade', :quote => "Heavy is good. Heavy is reliable. If it doesn't work you can always hit them.", :title => 'Snatch', :rank => 4}
    @charles = {:name => 'Charles De Mar', :quote => 'Go that way, really fast. If something gets in your way, turn.', :title => 'Better Off Dead', :rank => 3}
    @wolf    = {:name => 'The Wolf', :quote => 'I think fast, I talk fast and I need you guys to act fast if you wanna get out of this', :title => 'Pulp Fiction', :rank => 4}
    @glen    = {:name => 'Glengarry Glen Ross', :quote => "Put. That coffee. Down. Coffee is for closers only.",  :title => "Blake", :rank => 5}

    @fixtures = [@boris, @charles, @wolf, @glen]
  end

  def test_where_with_exact_match
    assert_equal [@wolf], @fixtures.where(:name => 'The Wolf')
  end

  def test_where_with_partial_match
    assert_equal [@charles, @glen], @fixtures.where(:title => /^B.*/)
  end

  def test_where_with_mutliple_exact_results
    assert_equal [@boris, @wolf], @fixtures.where(:rank => 4)
  end

  def test_with_with_multiple_criteria
    assert_equal [@wolf], @fixtures.where(:rank => 4, :quote => /get/)
  end

  def test_with_chain_calls
    assert_equal [@charles], @fixtures.where(:quote => /if/i).where(:rank => 3)
  end
end

puts WhereTest
```

all my tests say NoMethodError: undefined method `where' for # Array:0x000000027d6a20.

I'm not sure what the error means. I created a module with a class method that should be usable. The module's method should be available to WhereTest class with `extend Where`

Comment: Module methods (defined `def self.method...end`) are skipped over when the module is `include`d or `extend`ed in  a class. The only reason for defining a module method is to call the method on the module. [Math](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Math.html) is one such module. All methods defined in `Math` are module methods (e.g., `Math::sqrt`). Aside: suppose we have `module M; def m; end; end` and `class C; include M; end`. Then `M#m` becomes an instance method of `C`. It's curious that `m` is also referred to as an *instance method* of `M`, even though `M` does not have instances.

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that you are trying to call the `where` method on an instance of `Array` when there is no such method defined for arrays.

It seems that you want the `where` method added to the Array class (because you call `@fixtures.where` and `@fixtures` is an Array. However, you are adding it, instead, to the `WhereTest` class.

You would need to do something like:

```
class Array
  extend Where
end

class WhereTest < Minitest::Test
  def setup
  ...
```

Now, there are other issues with the code you present (patching a core class is dangerous, for example, and generally strongly recommended against). But this should at least get you a bit closer to what you’re trying to do.

Comment: I'm not sure how to proceed from here. I am constrained to keep the Where class as a module in a separate file. If i change extend to include, I can mix in the Where method as an instance method to the WhereTest class. But that gives me the same error.